# bootstrap : passing data between two modals

Tags: jquery, bootstrap-modal

I have modal 1 with :

Customer name 
Customer Number
"Link customer button"

When the user click on "Link customer button", the modal 2 is opened :

customer name

"search button"

when the user click on search button, he will have a list of customer, he should then select the right customer.

step 1 : pass customer name from modal 1 to modal 2 (already done)
step 2 : when the user select the right customer in modal 2, I would like to close modal2 and display customer Number in the modal 1

Can someone help me ?

you can find my code here : http://www.bootply.com/AGp9tttB54#

Answer (score 0):

You can try with one of these ways to manage data without reloading the page:

1) **DOM Manipulation**

Listen for [Bootstrap Modal events](https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/components/modal/#events), and update the `innerHTML` or the  `value` property from another element

2) **Reactive Data**

Use [VueJS](https://vuejs.org/) or Angular in order to model data without interacting with the DOM.

I personally recommend the 2nd way.

Answer (score 0):

try adding this:

```
$('#accModal').on('hide.bs.modal', function(e) {
    $('#oppModal').find('#opp-accid').val($('#accModal').find('#acc-id').val());
});
```